# How can I do line break in jinja2 python?

Tags: python, jinja2

How can I do line break in jinja2 in python?

Below is my code

```
t1 = Template("{% for i in range(0, a1) %}|{{ mylist1[i] }}{% for j in range(0, (20 - (mylist1[i]|length))) %}{{ space }}{% endfor %}|{{ dicts[mylist1[i]][dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]] }}{% for j in range(0, (20 - (dicts[mylist1[i]][dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]]|length))) %}{{ space }}{% endfor %}|\n{{ string }}{% endfor %}")
```

This code will result in:
[image]
Since it is horizontally too long, I want to write them in few lines.

However, If I do what I usually do in python like below:

```
t1 = Template("{% for i in range(0, a1) %}|\
               {{ mylist1[i] }}\
               {% for j in range(0, (20 - (mylist1[i]|length))) %}\
                    {{ space }}\
               {% endfor %}|\
               {{ dicts[mylist1[i]][dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]] }}\
               {% for j in range(0, (20 - (dicts[mylist1[i]][dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]]|length))) %}\
                   {{ space }}\
               {% endfor %}|\n\
               {{ string }}\
               {% endfor %}")
```

The result will be 
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python preserver spaces so you will see them in the results as well.

```
str = "{% for i in range(0, a1) %}|\"
str += "{{ mylist1[i] }}\"
str += "{% for j in range(0, (20 - (mylist1[i]|length))) %}\"
str += "{{ space }}\"
str += "{% endfor %}|\"
str += "{{ dicts[mylist1[i]][dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]] }}\"
str += "{% for j in range(0, (20 - (dicts[mylist1[i]]"
str += "[dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]]|length))) %}\"
str += "{{ space }}\"
str += "{% endfor %}|\n\"
str += "{{ string }}\"
str += "{% endfor %}")"

# and then use the generates string
t1 = Template(str);
```

Comment: `str` is already a built-in type. Nothing should not assigned to `str`, ever.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use string concatenation like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36866418/5492820). In your case take advantage of parentheses and [implicit string concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).

```
t1 = Template("{% for i in range(0, a1) %}|{{ mylist1[i] }}\n"
              "    {% for j in range(0, (20 - (mylist1[i]|length))) %}\n"
              "        {{ space }}\n"
              "    {% endfor %}|{{ dicts[mylist1[i]][dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]] }}\n"
              "    {% for j in range(0, (20 - (dicts[mylist1[i]][dicts[mylist1[i]].keys()[0]]|length))) %}\n"
              "        {{ space }}\n"
              "    {% endfor %}|\\n{{ string }}\n"  # Notice "\\n" to keep it for Jinja.
              "{% endfor %}")
```