# How to display jinja2 template (j2 file) in HTML page with correct format?

Tags: django, django-forms, jinja2, web-frameworks, html-templates

I'm able to display jija2 template on HTML page, but the output format is not correct.

```
current output is:
Your first name is Tom Your last name is Hanks
```

```
Expected output is:

Your first name is Tom
Your last name is Hanks
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader


class DbNames(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name")


def index(request):
    return render(request, "emps/index.html")


def form_gen(request):
    form = DbNames()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DbNames(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            file_loader = FileSystemLoader('emps/templates/emps')
            env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
            template = env.get_template('result.j2')
            output = template.render(form.cleaned_data)

            return render(request, "emps/output.html", {
                "form_data": output
            })
        else:
            print('ERROR')
    return render(request, "emps/users.html", {
        "form": form
    })
```

result.j2

```
Your first name is {{first_name}}
Your last name is {{last_name}}
```

Comment: can you set html tags like "<br>"? if not  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866128/how-can-i-do-line-break-in-jinja2-python

Comment: @hansTheFranz Already tried, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

it's not about jinja2 or django is in html you can use tags like

or  but if this dosen't work maybe you can use an ul like this :

```
<ul>
    <li>Your first name is {{first_name}}</li>
    <li>Your last name is {{last_name}}</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Or you can do `<p>Your first name is {{ first_name }}<p>` and then `<p>Your last name is {{ last_name }}<p>`.

Comment: @gunsodo i'm using a j2 template instead of HTML tags. I wanted to display result.j2 in my output.html.

Comment: that's the only way you can't orgnize things with jinja2 without html